# Define a required option with pgfopts

Tags: package-writing, pgfopts

I would like to define a required package option with `pgfopts`. So far I've done the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
    \ProvidesPackage{\jobname}[2018-01-24 v1.0 Test package]
    \RequirePackage{etoolbox, pgfopts}

    \pgfkeys{
        testproj/.cd,
        required entry/.store in = \myValue,
        required entry = {} % <-- Set default to empty
    }

    \newrobustcmd\mysetup[1]{\pgfqkeys{/testproj}{#1}}
    \ProcessPgfOptions{/testproj}

    \ifcsempty{myValue}{%
        \PackageError{\jobname}{Option required entry was not set}{help text}%
    }{}%

    \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{\jobname}

\mysetup{%
    required entry = test
}

\begin{document}
    myValue: \myValue
\end{document}
```

The Problem is that the PackageError is always raised. What I want is that the error is only raised when `required entry` within `\mysetup` isn't set or equals empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking too soon: the whole `.sty` is read before the rest of the preamble. So defer the check:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
  \ProvidesPackage{\jobname}[2018-01-24 v1.0 Test package]
  \RequirePackage{etoolbox, pgfopts}

  \pgfkeys{
    testproj/.cd,
    required entry/.store in = \myValue,
    required entry = {} % <-- Set default to empty
  }

  \newrobustcmd\mysetup[1]{\pgfqkeys{/testproj}{#1}}
  \ProcessPgfOptions{/testproj}

  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifcsempty{myValue}{%
      \PackageError{\jobname}{Option required entry was not set}{help text}%
    }{}%
  }

  \endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{\jobname}

\mysetup{%
    required entry = test
}

\begin{document}
    myValue: \myValue
\end{document}
```

Comment: This sounds logical. With your answer I've found another solution using a wrapper macro. `\newcommand{\getValue}{%
    \ifcsempty{myValue}{%
        \PackageError{\jobname}{Option required entry was not set}{help text}%
    }{\myValue}%
}`